# File upload with multiple browse button (populated from array) on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to upload file from dynamic upload button that generated form array as below code (Edited and workd already).

```
 @foreach( $transfer as $key => $item )
     <tr>
        <td>                                   
          <input type="file" name="document[]" class="doc filestyle"/>
        </td>
     </tr>
 @endforeach
```

This is boostrap filestyle

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.doc').filestyle({
      buttonName : 'btn-success',
      input: false,
      icon: false,
});
```

It only work for single file. But I have no idea for multiple. (Edited and workd already)

```
      if(count(Request::file('document', [])) > 0){
        foreach( Request::file('document', []) as $key => $item ){
            echo 'Reg ID: ' . $key . '<br />';
            echo 'Value: ' . $item->getClientOriginalName() . '<br />';
        }
    }
```

Thanks for all advise.

Comment: Use an array like this ```name="document[]"```, then ```foreach(Request::file('document') as $file)```

Comment: Thanks, work perfectly. I edited code for correction.

Comment: No problems. Best not edit your question with the correct answer.

Comment: Hi CUGreen, Thanks and noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are not defining your control name as array

Change This to

```
<input type="file" name="document"  id="doc{{$key}}" class="filestyle"/>
```

This

```
<input type="file" name="document[]"  id="doc{{$key}}" class="filestyle"/>
```

Not `name="document"` change to `name="document[]"`

and sorry i have missed `multiple` Attributes in tag thanks to  `@Md.Sukel Ali`

This Might Work

Answer (score 1):

You need to add multiple attribute in your in input field.

```
<input type="file" name="document[]"  id="doc{{$key}}" class="filestyle" multiple="" />
```